# c# combobox Items добавить в базу данных

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

Есть `ComboBox` значения (student, teacher, magister). В базе данных MySQL есть под такими же именами колонки student, teacher, magister. Теперь при выборе teacher нужно добавлять данные в колонку teacher.

Помогите пожалуйста как это сделать? У меня все параметры добавляются только в одну колонку.

```cs
private void Addbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    { 
        string query = "insert into sta(student, teacher, magister) Values (@student, @teacher, @magister)";
        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = AutoNumberedTable(dt);
        con.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@student", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = comboBox4.Items;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@teacher", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = comboBox4.Items;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@magister", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = comboBox4.Items;

        if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Added");
        }

        con.Close();

        spisok();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error!");
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: вставьте пожалуйста код текстом.

Comment: исправил, взгляните пожалуйста

Comment: `comboBox4.Items` - это же коллекция, что именно вы хотите добавить в базу? Быть может `comboBox4.SelectedValue`? Нужно больше подробностей.

Comment: у меня в базе данных есть 3 колонки под именем student, teacher,magister , я хочу в comboBox4 коллекциях выбрать teacher или magister или student и соответственно добавить в базу данных

Comment: я в комбобокс коллекцию добавил 3 параметра . пользователь выбирает student добавляет в базу и этот параметр должен добавляется в колонку student , выбирал teacher добавил должен добавляется в колонку teacher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас неправильная архитектура таблиц в БД.

Вы хотите получить

`sta`

| id | student | teacher | magister |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ivanov |  |  |
| 2 |  | Petrov |  |
| 3 |  |  | Sidorov |

Но с этими данными будет сложно работать, и потом, что делать если получится вот так?

`sta`

| id | student | teacher | magister |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ivanov |  | Ivanov |
| 2 | Petrov | Petrov |  |
| 3 | Sidorov |  | Sidorov |

Структура данных никак не защищает вас от такого рода ошибок

Сделайте другую таблицу типа

`sta`

| id | name | type_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ivanov | 0 |
| 2 | Petrov | 1 |
| 3 | Sidorov | 2 |

Где `type_id` - ссылка на другую таблицу

`types`

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | student |
| 1 | teacher |
| 2 | magister |

Как раз, вы сможете из этой таблицы заполнить `ComboBox` и по его же значению выставлять `type_id` в таблице с фамилиями.

Позднее вы познакомитесь с SQL `JOIN` и сможете доставать такие данные одним запросом из обеих таблиц, а не двумя, а пока попробуйте реализовать то что я предложил, даже разными запросами.

Comment: благодарю за информацию , но  у меня немного другая проблема,  я хочу хранить каждый элемент в коллекции отдельным столбцом в базе данных. то есть Фамилия Петров , Студент;  фамилия Ярушев magister и т.д

Comment: @jun66 я вам это и предлагаю, только другим способом. Любая строка таблицы содержит фиксированное количество ячеек. Вы не можете заполнить одну не заполняя остальные. Точнее вы можете положить туда NULL, но это все равно потребует от базы данных выделения памяти на VARCHAR выбранной вам длины, а так с базами данных делать нельзя.

Comment: мне  комбобокс нужен только для одного , он сокращает мне контроллер, я мог бы создать 3 чекбоксов под student, teacher, magister  , чекнул и добавился  запись в базе данных

Comment: @jun66 вы точно внимательно прочитали ответ и поняли, что там написано? Постарайтесь вникнуть.

Comment: понял , но такая структура баз данных для меня очень сложно реализовать данный момент, для начало просто добавить .

Comment: @jun66 то есть одну таблицу вы можете создать, а 2 - нет? странно :) Ну извините, вам нужно почитать про базы данных и понять, что такое 1-я, 2-я и 3-я нормальная форма. Если вникните в ответ и хотя-бы попытаетесь сделать правильно, вы поймете, что то что я предложил, сделать намного проще, чем то что вы задумали. `type_id` - это просто число, никакой магии.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь , попробую реализовать ваш вариант . кажется интересный и  правильный